# Pythonic way to detect final iteration of a loop

Tags: python

Currently, I do something like

```
count = 0
for item in list:
  if count == len(list) - 1:
      <do something>
   else:
      <do something else>
   count += 1
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to recognize the final iteration of a loop - for both lists and dictionaries?

Comment: Do you really need to know if its the last element? Usually you can get around this by using `', '.join(list)` for example.

Comment: @T.Nel it wasn't flagged as unhelpful, it was flagged as a duplicate, which it is.

Comment: Duplicate of which?

Comment: @Mawg, it seems your first question around here...

Comment: @Mawg of the two questions linked to as duplicates at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can improve on it using `enumerate()`:

```py
for i, item in enumerate(list):
    if i == len(list) - 1:
        <do something>
    else:
        <do something else>
```

Comment: you only need to calculate last item in list once `last_item = list[-1]`